# Trouble adding custom fonts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, flutter-dependencies

I am not getting an error when adding custom fonts in Flutter, but it is not applying the font.

I have tried a full rebuild, reinstall, and things I have read from other similar threads, but nothing has worked so far. Here is the part of my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Bauhaus
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Bauhaus.ttf
```

and here's an example of code...

```
                        new TextSpan(
                          text: 'Started!', 
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontSize: 50.0,
                            fontFamily: "Bauhaus",
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
```

It works with default things like "Times New Roman", but not custom fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u haven't configured Theme after run main function

like this:

```
fonts:
    - family: SFUIText
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIText-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIText-Semibold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/SFUIText-RegularItalic.ttf
          style: italic


final app = MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: mColorIcon),
          primaryColor: mColorPrimary,
          accentColor: mColorAccent,
          backgroundColor: mColorBackground,
          indicatorColor: mColorPrimary,
          splashColor: mColorPrimary,
          canvasColor: mColorCanvas,
          appBarTheme: Styles.appBar,
          fontFamily: 'SFUIText',
          textTheme: TextTheme(
              title: Styles.title,
              body1: Styles.textSecondary,
              body2: Styles.textSecondaryBold,
              headline: Styles.headline,
              subhead: Styles.subHeading,
              button: Styles.button,
              overline: Styles.overline)), ...);
```